# ANTLR check for matching XML start and end tags

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

When using ANTLR to parse XML, can ANTLR validate that an end tag matches its start tag? The XML parser in the ANTLR book doesn’t check for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine a generic approach like this (but never actually tried it myself):

```
tag: openTag = TAG_OPEN content closeTag = TAG_CLOSE { tagsMatch($openTag, $closeTag); }?;
```

You'd use a validating predicate to fail the entire rule if the tag parts don't match. Might give you problems with error reporting, but that can be solved.

Comment: $openTag provides access to the *tree* produced by TAG_OPEN?

Comment: Yes, exactly (https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md). Might be we can just omit the `openTag` and `closeTag` labels and use `$TAG_OPEN` and `$TAG_CLOSE` directly. The function tagsMatch() can use target language to access the token values (e.g. the text).

Comment: Yes, this sure sounds like it will work.  Who needs a stack when you have a tree :-?

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary XML tags, a context free parser can't do this.  ANTLR in its pure state is essentially context-free.

You can hack most parsers (probably including ANTLR) to build a tag stack.  When  `<tagname...` gets parsed (or lexed as you find convenient), you can push the tag name on the stack.  When `</tagname...`  is parsed/lexed, you can match the tagname to the top of the stack, and complain if a mismatch occurs.

I used the lexer version in my XML parser (see bio), seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks @Ira Baxter, my use case actually involves more than just validating tags (was trying to keep the question simple), so I'm hoping to find a context sensitive parser. I see from [one of your SO posts in 2011](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126779/parsing-context-sensitive-language) that you weren't aware of any context sensitive parser at that time, has that since changed? A quick search didn't turn anything up.

Comment: Hacking the parser as I described converts it into a context-sensitive one that works just fine for this purpose.  You can work with a designed-to-be-context-sensitive parser if you wish (see entry for MetaS at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_grammar)  but that won't get any advantage over the hack.    [You'll discover that all language front-ends are context-sensitive; they tend to use context free parsing with additional ad hoc checking for the context sensitive part).